# Is it cruel that God punishes us with eternal hell?

Tags: nature-of-god

Although it may seem appealing to have a second chance after death, we also get many many chances on earth to believe in Christ. (Just to clarify I am not meaning to question God or his plan, for he is the king of all kings and he knows all):

- God loves us, he really does, but it ***seems*** like he doesn’t care if we suffer after death, right? Because as Hebrews 9:27 says: “27 And just as it is appointed for man to die once, and after that comes judgment”, we don’t get a ‘second’ chance after death.
- God created us, but why, why did he create us if he meant for Adam and Eve to sin, if he meant for us to have free will, which in turn, he knew many people would turn away from his arms?

People sometimes never get to know God, and it is our job as Christians to help them. But, sometimes people don’t change, as we have free will. Otherwise we would be robotic servants, and that’s not what God wants. So why? Why does he create us if the only reason is to believe in him. Isn’t that almost the same as being robotic. If we don’t we are sent to eternal suffering. Of course we want to be with him (I could go on debating with myself all day) though. I’m looking for a second though on this matter. Thanks -mouse

Comment: I think this question may need a rework to be suitable for the site as there is no 'right' answer phrased as is. Personally, I think it would be cruel for God to torment us eternally (directly or indirectly) and believe sinners are destroyed in hell once and for all, not tormented.

Comment: Basically, hell is eternal separation from God. It is basically showing how empty life is without God. We are given many many many chances on earth to believe in him. (Based on what you believe to get into his kingdom) This question was for different thought on this topic, personally, I believe God has reasons that we don’t understand yet.  He desires for us to come to be with him, and it hurts him when we turn away from his arms.

Answer (score 0):

> to have a second chance after death

There isn't any biblical support that anyone gets a second chance.
(Does any denomination say that individuals will be given a second chance?)

> it seems like he doesn't care if we suffer after death, right?

There isn't any biblical support for God's not caring.
Nor is there any support for anything other than possibly brief suffering after death.

1 Titus 2:3 says "*who desires all men to be saved and to come to the knowledge of the truth*".
That sounds like he *does* care.

> why did he create us … if he meant for us to have free will?

God wants his children to freely choose to follow his way.
He created mankind to be his loving family, not his mindless slaves.

The key to understanding is to realize that in this current age:

- God allows Satan to remain as the god of this world.

  - "*the god of this world hath blinded the minds of them which believe not*" — 2 Corinthians 4:4
  - "*Now is the judgment of this world: now shall the prince of this world be cast out.*" — John 12:31
- God is not trying to save mankind now.

  - If he was, we'd have to conclude that for 2000 years he's been doing a very poor job of it, which doesn't make sense for the omnipotent being that was capable of creating the entire universe.
- Only a small number of elect will be offered salvation at this time.

  - "*And except that the Lord had shortened those days, no flesh should be saved: but for the elect's sake, whom he hath chosen, he hath shortened the days.*" — Mark 13:20
  - "*For false Christs and false prophets shall rise, and shall shew signs and wonders, to seduce, if it were possible, even the elect.*" — Mark 13:22
  - "*And then shall he send his angels, and shall gather together his elect from the four winds, from the uttermost part of the earth to the uttermost part of heaven.*" — Mark 13:27
  - "*Fear not, little flock; for it is your Father's good pleasure to give you the kingdom.*" — Luke 12:32
- The vast majority of mankind was not only not offered salvation, they never even heard of the possibility.

  - Consider the billions of people that lived and died before Jesus appeared, and the even more billions that right up until recently had no chance of ever hearing Jesus's message.
- Just as the nation of Israel was chosen to be a physical example (of both good and bad) to the world, spiritual Israel (true Christians) are chosen to be a spiritual example to the world, not to convert it.

  - "*Let your light so shine before men, that they may see your good works, and glorify your Father which is in heaven.*" — matthew 5:16
  - "*In all things shewing thyself a pattern of good works: in doctrine shewing uncorruptness, gravity, sincerity, Sound speech, that cannot be condemned; that he that is of the contrary part may be ashamed, having no evil thing to say of you.*" — Titus 2–7,8
  - "*be thou an example of the believers, in word, in conversation, in charity, in spirit, in faith, in purity.*" — 1 Timothy 4:12
  - "*Be careful to live properly among your unbelieving neighbors. Then even if they accuse you of doing wrong, they will see your honorable behavior, and they will give honor to God when he judges the world.*" — 1 Peter 2:12 (NLT)

Comment: +1While this is only Christianity-SE, it would be great to have some Biblical support for the truths listed for whoever wanders past here again.

Comment: @steveowen, thanks for the suggestion.